# Remove dollar sign from query on Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am working on a website where there is a donate box with a field and a contribute button.

```
<div id="donate-bar">
    <form name="donate" id="donate">
        <span class="donate-text">DONATE</span>
        <input type="text" class="amount" name="amount" id="amount" value="$10" size="5">
        <input type="submit" id="contribute" formaction="https://website.com/donate" accept-charset="utf-8" formmethod="GET" value="CONTRIBUTE">
    </form>
</div>
```

However, the query gets sent to the donation processor's website as `https://website.com/donate?amount=%2410` and doesn't tick the $10 box. If I remove the `$` and submit the query again the value is sent and the correct amount is seen on the second page.

Is there an easy way using PHP or Javascript to have it remove the `$` when the form is submitted so that `https://website.com/donate?amount=%2410` changes to `https://website.com/donate?amount=10`.

I've tried a couple of things but nothing I've tried has worked. Some examples of code would be super helpful since I'm newer to some of this. Can I parse it as integer on submit? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "I've tried a couple of things" Such as…?

Comment: string.replace("$","")  -.-

Comment: You could just do `$<input type="number" name="amount" />`

Comment: [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: if you don't have to worry about legacy use html5. check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963158/html5-form-input-pattern-currency-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form#donate').on('submit',function() {
  var $input = $('input#amount');
  $input.val(parseInt($input.val().replace(/\$/,''),10));
});
```

Comment: Please don't use `parseInt` without the `radix` parameter... That's a bad habit to teach others.

Comment: It should also be checked in PHP; Don't trust the client.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! I know I should probably use a PHP fix to be more compatible but in cases where JS is disabled it would just go to a donate page where they'll have to input an amount a second time. Thanks a million!

Comment: @user3791008 it's a very small change in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Why not put the Dollar sign outside of the input and store the value as "10":

```
<div id="donate-bar">
  <form name="donate" id="donate">
    <span class="donate-text">DONATE</span>
     $<input type="text" class="amount" name="amount" id="amount" value="10" size="5">
 <input type="submit" id="contribute" formaction="https://website.com/donate" accept-charset="utf-8" formmethod="GET" value="CONTRIBUTE"></form></div>
```

Comment: `<input type="number" ` would be a useful change too

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['amount'] = str_replace("$", "", $_POST['amount']);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to fix this.

First of all, one of my suggeestions is that you change the field to

```
type="number"
```

Second of all, in PHP, you can use the following to remove the dollar sign:

```
$amount = str_replace('$', '', $_REQUEST['amount']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function in jquery as follows

> var value = ($('#amount').val()).split('$'); 
>   var amount = value[1] ;

In PHP

> $value = explode('$',$_POST['amount']); //results array elements
>   without $ symbols $amount = $value[1];

Or also in PHP

> $amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_POST['amount']);

//gets only integer parts and omits all other

Also in PHP

> $amount = str_replace('$', '', $_POST['amount']);

Comment: First example is going out of the,way a littlebit. Why create an array when the third example does what op wishes with less micro performance?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps the simplest way is a hidden field:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //number regex - the format $10
      var regex = /\$[1-9][0-9]+/;

      //Setting validations
      $(document).on('blur', '#pretty_amount', function() {
        if(!regex.test($(this).val())) {
           //Do something probably clear field
           alert("Error Invalid number: " + $(this).val());
        } else {
           var newValue = $(this).val().match(/[1-9][0-9]+/g);
           $('#amount').val(newValue);$('#amount').innerHtml(newValue);
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="donate-bar">
    <form name="donate" id="donate">
      <span class="donate-text">DONATE</span>
      <input type="text" style="display: none;" name="amount" id="amount">
      <input type="text" class="amount" name="pretty_amount" id="pretty_amount" value="$10" size="6">
   <input type="submit" id="contribute" formaction="https://website.com/donate" accept-charset="utf-8" formmethod="GET" value="CONTRIBUTE"></form></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This does what you want, if I'm not mistaken.

Best regards