# Parse amount in input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input in my form where the user have to write an amount to pay. The problem is that the user have different ways to do it, it could be 1,350.55 (this is he correct one), but it could be something like this 1.350,55 or 1.350. So, is there any way to parse the amount to my correct form?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to know the format before parsing, and you could use numeraljs to help you parse it.

Comment: I think this question is equivalent to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963158/html5-form-input-pattern-currency-format

Comment: what does this mean `1.350,55`??

Comment: @entre in Spanish and other latin languages, the comma is a thousands separators, and the low dot is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to parse the input, right?
Why not try to make the input a currency field? 
And then parse it into a container through angular, so that customers may see the value and then work with the angular filtered value.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/lacrioque/vouLmrac/

```
<p><label for='numberinput'>Your Price here: </label><input type='number' name='numberinput' ng-model='numbertofilter' placeholder="1,350.99"/></p>
<p>Price: <span>{{numbertofilter | currency }}</span></p>
```

Comment: I think it's the perfect solution. Thanks @Lacrioque

Answer (score 0):

## Use ng-pattern

Attach ng-pattern to your input and feed it a RegEx of your required pattern. This way people will only be able to input in the correct way and you can avoid bad data.

Please check out [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) for more information on input formatting.

## Example

Here I have an example for any whole number up to `9999999` its very simple if you understand RegEx

```
<input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" 
       ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required>
```

## Note

You can check your RegEx [here](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the format, how would you parse `13.995`? Would it be "13955" (an integer) or the float one?

You may instead want to mask the format and avoid thousand separators entirely. And tell the user not to use them.