# How to get automatic dots in number input?

Tags: html, input, numbers

I couldn't find any answer to my problem. I have an input with type="number" and I want the number to automatically add dots to it when it goes up to 1000. So instead of 1000 it should output 1.000, is there a possibility to do that? Like adding some attribute to the input?

Comment: use javascript for this.

Comment: what did you tried so far?? Add codes in our question

Comment: There are some different solutions shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963158/html5-form-input-pattern-currency-format

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to add them. Try this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rsTCO8hmZUSEtrvpuWE6?p=preview

If you just need one dot a simple way would be this:

```
  <input type="number" onkeyup="oneDot(this)"/>
```

And in JS:

```
  function oneDot(input) {
    var value = input.value,
        value = value.split('.').join('');

    if (value.length > 3) {
      value = value.substring(0, value.length - 3) + '.' + value.substring(value.length - 3, value.length);
    }

    input.value = value;
  }
```