# How to add automatic dots to prices in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, price

I'm trying to implement automatic formatting to an web-page. So that when you type 12345678, it is automatically €123.456,78.

```
      <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" required class="form-control" name="EKBrutto" placeholder="EK-Brutto">
```

I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML text input field with currency symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913236/html-text-input-field-with-currency-symbol)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963158/html5-form-input-pattern-currency-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following link to mask money, Especially you are dealing with money

https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/

And this following link is a demo

http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/

basically what you have is:

```
<input type="text" id="currency" />
```

then you put in this script

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#currency').maskMoney();
  })
</script>
```

This automatically puts the dots in place, but there are more parameters to help you just read the guide :)