# webinput html5 input method keypad lower

Tags: css, mobile

Playing with mobile css adaptation and wonder if it is possible to set input keypad on mobile devices to standard keypad in lower mode?

```
<input type="number"> -> sets to numeric keypad

<input type="text"> -> sets to standard keypad
```

Possible with CSS or JS?

Regards

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963158/html5-form-input-pattern-currency-format ?

Comment: Anyways, I think what you're looking for is : < input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" / >

Comment: Perhaps I need to elaborate. I look for the option to start the text keypad with lowercase letters.

Comment: Doesn't it depend of your phone settings, wether you want the first letter to be capitalised of not? If so, no theres no way (no way that i personnaly know. Sry).

Comment: Having the feeling.. that you are correct.. arg ;-)