# What is the pattern for dollar and cents in html form input number?

Tags: php, input, stripe-payments

I want to allow users to input only 2 digits for cents in input type number not 3 or more digits.

Allowed format - $22.45

Not Allowed Format - $22.452

Example -

```
<input style="width:150px!important;" type="number" name="price" min="1" step="any" required placeholder="Amount" title="Enter payment amount" class="form-control" />
```

What input pattern should I use for this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you looking for this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963158/80836 ?

Comment: See you my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code is:

```
<input style="width: 150px !important;" type="number" name="price" min="1" step="0.01" required placeholder="Amount" title="Enter payment amount" class="form-control" />
```

You miss to declare: `step="0.01"`...

Hope this helps.