# HTML Input pattern for "currency" field

Tags: html, regex

Attempting to use a regex pattern for an HTML input element that limits the characters to 0-9, ",","-",".","$"

I have very little experience in regex and used the pattern=[0-9,.-$] on the input element and it does not work.  Though I plan on studying regex intensely in the future, I need a little help on this for now.  Thank you.

```html
<form>
  <input name="currency" pattern=[0-9,.-$]>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963158/html5-form-input-pattern-currency-format

Answer (score 0):

don't use regex, use native `type="number"` that will do job for you with no need for regex

coverage is almost full > https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="currency">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't put the special characters I outlined in the question into a `type="number"`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

- `-` indicates a **range**, you already used it as such for `0-9`. `.-$` isn't a valid range. [A validator](https://validator.nu/) would have highlighted this for you. You need to escape the `-`.
- You are only matching **one** character. You need to match **multiple** so use something like `+` to mean *one or more*

```html
<form>
  <input name="currency" pattern="[0-9,.\-$]+">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I just ran you snippet and was able to type anything I wanted in the field.

Comment: @Elcid_91 — The `pattern` attribute doesn't prevent people from typing what they like. It prevents form submission when the value doesn't match. That's why I added the form and the submit button.